# Task in DAG tries to run while already running

Tags: task, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

using **Apache Ariflow**:

We have created a DAG that runs everyday at 07:00 AM: `schedule_interval='0 7 * * *'` 
The task is searching for a new row in a certain table. If it sees a new row, it continues to execute more tasks and so on.

We want the task to run for 19 hours. If it did not find a new row in that table, it will skip the rest of the tasks. The task's timeout is: `timeout=60 * 60 * 19`

Recently we have found that after 12 hours of running, we get an error which prompts the task to fail. Because we have a retry, the task retrires and then runs fully for 19 hours.

So instead of 19 hours, we get a run of 31 hours.

Here is the error:

`INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: DAG_NAME.check_for_new_file 2021-06-28T07:00:00+00:00 [running]>, dependency 'Task Instance State' FAILED: Task is in the 'running' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.`

Has anyone experienced this error? If I seem to understand correctly, the task is trying to run again after 12 hours, so the task is being changed to a 'failed' instead of 'running' state?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you redacted the names in the error message? Is `check_for_new_file` the Dag you are referring to in the question?

Comment: @sophros Yes, DAG_NAME is a generic name for a DAG (we have about 20 with the exact same issue, all failing at ounce). `check_for_new_file` is the name of the task.

Comment: What kind of error do you have after 12 hours?

Comment: @bruno-uy the error I put in the post: INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: DAG_NAME.check_for_new_file 2021-06-28T07:00:00+00:00 [running]>, dependency 'Task Instance State' FAILED: Task is in the 'running' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.

Comment: Can you provide more context about the `check_for_new_file` task? Mostly what are the parameters you use and arguments for the DAG definition.